# Eventos USB en Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, manejo-de-memoria

Alguien conoce cómo escuchar eventos sobre los puertos USB en Python, por ejemplo saber si se conectó una memoria usb.

Comment: Revisad estos enlaces :D
http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/53223/win32gui.WNDCLASS - http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/

Comment: esto es solo en linux o funciona tanbien en windows?

Answer (score 0):

Usa **udev** directamente (mediante **libudev**, a través **pyudev**).

```
import pyudev
context = pyudev.Context()
monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
observer = pyudev.pygtk.GUDevMonitorObserver(monitor)
observer.connect('device-added', device_added_callback)
observer.connect('device-changed', device_changed_callback)
monitor.enable_receiving()
mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()
mainloop.run()
```

Traducción de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5111493/1481040